# Android - how do I save a file to a subdirectory of the main app's directory?

Tags: java, android, java-io

I'm trying to save a bitmap to a specific folder in the private app's directory but android is having none of it. I can save files in the main directory and I can create subdirectories but I cannot save files to the subdirectories. I Here's the method I'm using:

```
public void saveBitMap(String fileName, Bitmap bitMap, String album){
    //Creating the subdirectory. This works
     File albumDir=new File(getFilesDir(), album);
     albumDir.mkdirs();
     albumDir.setWritable(true);
     albumDir.setWritable(true);
     fileName = albumDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName;

//Creating the file in the subdirectory. This doesn't work  
     FileOutputStream outputStream;
     try {
          outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          bitMap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
          outputStream.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

    //Checking that the files and folders have been saved
     File dir = getFilesDir();
     for(File f: dir.listFiles()){
          Log.d("ggg", f.getName());
          if(f.isDirectory()){
               Log.d("ggg",f.list().length+"");
               for(String g:f.list()){
                    Log.d("ggg", g +" "+ f);
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What does filename contains.   By "doesn't work" do you mean you catch an exception?  If so what is the exception message?   Show the log messages you are writing.

Comment: I don't see a outputStream.write(bytes) call anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnJSmith - that would be inside the implementation of Bitmap.compress() which takes an OutputStream as an argument.